# Run docker command inside jenkins container in WSL2 Permission denied

Tags: docker, jenkins, debian, wsl-2

I have Docker Desktop installed on my Windows 10 notebook on a debian distro. The problem I have is when I want to run docker inside a container with jenkins.

I create the jenkins container with a docker-compose:

```
version:             '2.4'
services:
  jenkins:
    image:           jenkins/jenkins
    user:            root
    privileged:      true
    container_name:  jenkins
    restart:         unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 8443:8443
      - 50000:50000
    group_add:
      - 1000
    volumes:
      - jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home
      - /c/Users/user/.docker/config.json:/root/.docker/config.json:ro 
      - /c/Users/user/.docker/machine/certs:/root/.docker:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /usr/local/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker 
    environment:
      - JENKINS_OPTS="--prefix=/jenkins"
```

When I run the container, I get in by running:

```
>docker exec -it -u root jenkins sh
>docker
>sh: docker: Permission denied
```

and won't let me do anything else. I can't build images in pipelines either.

I read everything I found in google but nothing helped me. Some guides say to create add the jenkins user to the docker group, but that does not help me because I am running jenkins in a container.

I exposed the address `tcp://0.0.0.0:2375` and it didn't work.

I created an intermediate container with "alpine/socat" but it didn't work either.

**How can I do to run docker commands inside the jenkins container, being in WSL?**

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to run docker command inside docker container?

Comment: Exactly. I recently migrated from Docker Tool Box to Docker Desktop with WSL and ran into this problem. Before adding a couple of environment variables it worked fine and didn't have any problems. But now with the Docker Tool Box, I can't run docker commands inside containers and I don't know what settings I am missing or have wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution in this link: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1480#issuecomment-355671606

For those who come looking for the solution for the same problem, you just have to install the docker client and that's it.

`curl -sSL https://download.docker.com/linux/static/stable/x86_64/docker-17.09.1-ce.tgz | sudo tar -C /usr/local/bin -xz --strip=1 docker/docker`

In my case, it was not necessary to put export `DOCKER_HOST=tcp://localhost:2375` because Docker Desktop already exposes that port. If I added it, I got the error `Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://localhost: 2375. Is the docker daemon running?`, so I didn't put it.